# How can I make a console window open with my distributed app?

Tags: python

How can I make a console window open with my distributed app? I want that because that is where my output will be. When distribute it with a exe a console wont open so I cant see my output, I am using Tkinter to make the app and cx_freeze to distribute. Any help?

Comment: Add more details: how did you create the executable?

Comment: Also which package you are using to make app? Tkinter, pyqt.....?

Comment: Provide your code as well! @Josef how did you create the executable

Comment: @Josef does my answer solves your problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you using pyinstaller to create executabile file, dont use --noconsole flag, because is hiding it
2. Make sure that the program is succesfuly compiled

Comment: Without any information, how you can be sure OP is using `pyinstaller` to make executable? And additionally you don't have to answer these type of unclear questions!

Answer (score 0):

If you create the executable with [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) you can ignore the flag **-windowed** to avoid opening just the window. By default, when you convert a .py file to exe using pyinstaller, it opens up the terminal as well.

> pyinstaller --onefile -i"optional-icon.ico" filename.py

**--onefile** is also a flag you can ignore.

Comment: Without any information, how you can be sure OP is using `pyinstaller` to make executable? And additionally you don't have to answer these type of unclear questions!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

**Setup file** :

```
import cx_Freeze
# To display console :
exe = [cx_Freeze.Executable("<>")]
# To hide console :
exe = [cx_Freeze.Executable("<>", base = "Win32GUI")] 
# I think you wrote this rather then previous one

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "<>",
    version = "1.0",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages": [<>],
    executables = exe
)
```